# How to add lamps?

Tags: lighting

Day 3 Blender super noob. I'm following this tutorial, trying to make a mushroom, and all's been fine until it's asking me to put a lamp in the scene where there is no option to. I've looked around and everything says it's simply Shift+A or Add menu -> Lamp -> Point or w/e but everything I have tried hasn't come up with the "Lamp" option.

[Mushroom Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/49955/blender-tutorial-for-beginners-how-to-make-a-mushroom)

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that this tutorial and what information I've found about adding lamps is all for older versions. Thank you!

Comment: Exit edit mode (by pressing tab) then try.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lamps can only be added in Object Mode.

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit Edit Mode and you should be able to add a light.

Why?

You cannot add different kind of data to an object. If you are dealing with a mesh object, you can only add mesh information, not curves, empties or other kind of data. In other words, **a lamp cannot be part of the object**.

Read: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html#modeling-modes

Comment: Whoops, guess I should have tried that lol. Thanks